# Refresh text editor SQL Server Management Studio v17.9

Tags: sql, sql-server

Typically I develop SQL expressions using a fully featured text editor external to SSMS v17. I then await the SSMS Editor to reload the text before  execution of the expression. Often the reload take several seconds, sometimes a minute or more.

While one might copy and paste from editor to editor, is there a manual means of forcing the SSMS text editor to update? (Something akin to the F5 key in a browser window?)

Comment: You mean you've opened the same text file on two different editors, SSMS and another one,  and want SSMS to reload the file when it changes, like VS Code's or Sublime's `Revert File`? No. A browser's F5 reload isn't like that at all - just like SSMS's Execute(F9) it sends a new request and displays new results

Comment: Yes. The SQL expression is visible simultaneously in two separate text editors, the SSMS text editor and perhaps Notepad++ (on Windows). The majority of text editing is done in the fully featured text editor (Notepad++). After saving the file, the SSMS text editor updates, albeit slowly. Is there a means of speeding the update?

Comment: As I said, no, unless you close and reopen the file. Other editors have a `Revert File` command, like Sublime and VS Code, but SSMS doesn't

Comment: Azure Data Studio (essentially VS Code for SQL despite the name) on the other hand, inherits `Revert` from VS Code and detects changes a lot faster. It probably has far more features like Notepad++ too.